# How do I use JS Include and Replace inside a map in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to check the string in the array of strings to see if it contains the word "Heading". If so I want to format the element differently and remove the word heading from the element.

This is how I do it in C# in ASP.net Core. Its drawing from the same data that I want to use in react.

```
 @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)ViewData["Conditions"])
    {
        if (item.ToString().Contains("Heading"))
        {
            <div id="team" class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <h3> @item.ToString().Replace("Heading", "")</h3>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 text-left">@item.ToString()</div>
        }
    }
```

In ReactJS I have started with the following. It works just as long as I don't use the If statement. So how do I use JS Include and Replace inside a map?

```
const ConditionsList = props => {
return (
<div class="row">
  {props.conditions.map((item, index) => {
    if ({ item.includes("heading") }) {
        return (
          <div class="col col-md-12">{item}</div>
        );
      }
      else
      {
        return (
          <div class="col col-md-3">
            <Card className="cardBody">
              <CardText className="conditions " Key={index}>
                {item}
              </CardText>
            </Card>
          </div>
        );
    };
        })}
</div>
);
};
```

It doesn't like { item.includes("heading") } and I suspect it won't like my attempt at Replace either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `if else` inside JSX, you can use ternary

```
const ConditionsList = props => {
return (
<div class="row">
  {props.conditions.map((item, index) => {
    return  item.includes("heading") ?  <div class="col col-md-12">{item}</div>
                                     : <div class="col col-md-3">
            <Card className="cardBody">
              <CardText className="conditions " Key={index}>
                {item}
              </CardText>
            </Card>
          </div>
     };
  </div>
 );
};
```

[`If else in JSX`](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)